# Preventing using for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I have written the below MATLAB code. I want to know how can I optimize it without using for loop.
Any help will be very appreciated.

**MATLAB code:**

```
%Some parameters:
s = 50;
k = 50;
r = 0.1;
v = 0.2;
t = 2;
n=10000;

% Calculate CT by calling EurCall function 
CT = EurCall(s, k, r, v, t, n);

%Function EurCall to be called
function C = EurCall(s, k, r, v, t, n)
X = zeros(n,1);
hh = zeros(n,1);

for ii = 1 : n
    X(ii) = normrnd(0, 1);
    SS = s*exp((r - v^2/2)*t + v*X(ii)*sqrt(t));
    hh(ii) = exp(-r*t)*max(SS - k, 0);    
end %end for loop
C = (1/n) * sum(hh); 
end %end function
```

Comment: Why do you want to not use a loop? There is a belief that loops are slow in MATLAB, but this hasn’t been the case for many, many years now. Is this code too slow? Is this the bottleneck in your computations? Do you really need to speed it up? If so, ask for ways to speed it up. Please don’t just remove loops because you’ve heard they are slow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vectorized Approach:

Here is a vectorized approach that I think replicates the same functionality as the original script. Instead of looping this example declares `X` as a vector of size n by 1. By using element-wise multiplication `.*` we can effectively calculate the remaining vectors `SS` and `hh` without need to loop through the indices. In this case `SS` and `hh` will also be vectors of size n by 1. I do agree with comment above that MATLAB's for-loops are no longer inherently slow.

```
%Some parameters:
s = 50;
k = 50;
r = 0.1;
v = 0.2;
t = 2;
n=10000;

% Calculate CT by calling EurCall function 
[CT] = EurCall(s, k, r, v, t, n);

%Function EurCall to be called
function [C] = EurCall(s, k, r, v, t, n)
X = zeros(n,1);
hh = zeros(n,1);
mu = 0; sigma = 1;

%Creating a vector of normal random numbers of size (n by 1)%
X = normrnd(mu,sigma,[n 1]);
SS = s*exp((r - v^2/2)*t + v.*X.*sqrt(t));
hh = exp(-r*t)*max(SS - k, 0);   
C = (1/n) * sum(hh); 

end %end function
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**